# How did I get these strange electric shocks?

Tags: electrostatics

While doing experiment on designing & fabricating temparature controller circuit using a thermistor, this strange thing happened.Me & my friend frequently experienced short pulses of electric shock frequently while touching almost any random items for almost an hour while doing experiment.
The experiment consisted of:
A thermistor immersed in a beaker full of water and connected to + &  ground of a power source.A spiralled iron coil connected to power & immersed in water.This coil is powered throughout the experiment to heat the water.We both cleared the hot water after completing sets of experiment & got skin contact with that water.
So, why did we get electric shocks?

Comment: Not really enough information here to say for sure - but I would say you had a very dangerous setup and could have got much more hurt than you did. I believe your water heater lacked proper insulation / isolation. Please, before you do this again, have someone with electrical knowledge check your setup very carefully. You could have got very hurt.

Comment: Sounds like faulty electrical isolation to me... for what it's worth (assuming that you value your life and that of others), install a ground fault interruptor and establish proper grounding. Measure the current trough the leakage path (without putting yourself into the loop!)  and replace all parts in your circuit that show significant leakage immediately. It is good laboratory practice to add isolation transformers to all such setups.

Comment: @CuriousOne - insulation and isolation. We wrote the same thing four seconds apart...

Comment: @Floris: Potato-potato. I think we can agree on good lab practices... an electric shock sensation plus water is a timeout unless someone wants to turn it into a biology experiment.

Comment: Please consider these: We did not touch any circuit parts when the power was on and we got shock sometimes even when we touched some other person.Under these circumstances as per your comments it was due to faulty ground/isolation of lab instruments.Am I right?

Comment: It's a good guess. But having an electrician look at it would be a good idea.

Comment: Did the temperature controller have a relay inside it?  Did the shocks occur at all times or only when the temperature controller was switching off the current?

Comment: One can't debug an electrical circuit remotely and without measurements. What you are describing could be harmless electrostatic shocks or it could be a dangerous condition in the circuit you are dealing with. When in doubt have someone take care of this. An experienced physicist or electrical engineer will know what to do, but they have to be there and attach measurement equipment.

Comment: Temparature controller had a relay inside.We got static charge on our body at some point of experiment we don't know , so this static charge discharged giving us shock which happened irrespective of temparature controller switching on or off the current.How & why static charge got on us?

Comment: If you think the shocks you got were static electricity I would take a look at the floor. What kind of carpeting? Were you sitting in a chair that rolled? What were you wearing on your feet? Was it cold outside? There are so many possible answers - you do not give enough information for a thoughtful and informed answer.